# Logstash service failure CentOS7 - Some newbie questions

Tags: service, logstash

I am really struggling to launch logstash as a service on CentOS 7. Since I cannot figure out what or where to set the

-DJava.io.tmpdir= variable (which apparently would solve my issue), I am trying to create a little script to launch the logstash command line on boot.

The following line works manually for me:

```
 sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d
```

That successfully loads and opens port 5000.

So I am trying to create a boot time script to run that line and start logstash.
My problem is that I think I need the sudo command as it fails to run without it. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

I have the following files /etc/systemd/system/mylogstash.service:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disk-space-check.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and also /usr/local/bin/mylogstashstart.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d
```

To make the script executable I have done:
   chmod 744 /usr/local/bin/mylogstash.sh
and
   chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/mylogstash.service

It fails to execute as there are insufficient permissions. How do I replicate the Sudo in the script without storing a password and do I even need to?
Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong please? I'm getting pretty desperate, and no-one likes to see a man desperate...

Thanks,
QR